# delphi live bindings filter a combo box

Tags: delphi, combobox, refresh, controls, livebindings

I have 2 combo boxes link to a table looking up values in a type and subtype tables. When the users select the first I need to filter the data in the second.

Example data:

```
Tables
type     subtype
vehicle  car
vehicle  truck
vehicle  4-wheeler
boat     v-hull
boat     flat-bottom
```

Before live bindings you could filter and refresh the second data lookup (subtype) on the before popup event of the second  or on the close or change event of the first combo box. When I try this using live bindings it has not effect. I also tried to use the `Bindlist.Notify` method with no success.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you tried so far ?

Comment: Just kick off the livebindings and do that by yourself in code. There are a lot of bugs on updating the data and IMHO LB is just for some small examples but not for real use in applications.

Comment: @SirRufo I would be interested in some discussion of your opinion. Are there any articles you could cite in support, or to the contrary?

Comment: @HughJones I just posted a small LB example [here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/182139-%5Bxe7%5D-livebindings-datasets-und-listviews.html) and **maybe** I am doing it all wrong ... but if not, the LB is not ready for shipping. The project can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/amw7bystqp4f4za/LB_DB_Test.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup an master detail relationship between the main table and the subtype table. When the type was selected it set the value on the main table and filtered the subtype. I toggled the Active property on the LinkFillControlToField it refresh the list.

```
procedure TframeEquipmentEdit.cbbSubtypeClassEnter(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
begin
LinkFillControlToField10.Active := False;
LinkFillControlToField10.Active := True;
end;
```

Thanks for your comments and help

Wade

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fragment from a project I am working on today.  For 'Letter' read 'Type', for 'Template' read 'SubType'

```
procedure TdlgNewTemplate.LetterTypesComboChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTemplatesDs.Filter := Format('TYPE=%d',[LetterType()]);
  FTemplatesDs.Filtered := True;
  PopulateTemplatePaths();
end;
```

It is not a livebindings example.  With Livebindings I would guess the call to PopulateTemplatePaths would not be required, but all it does is clear the subtypes combobox and repopulate. (rather in the manner Sir Rufo suggests above, I think).